# Calculus: $f(n) = n$ for two distinct values of $n$ implies that for some $x$, $f'(x) = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm currently taking an upper level high school calculus class and am struggling with this question. I don't really know where to start so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, have you studied the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Another fun challenge is to draw some functions like this and see if they all have this property and why.

Comment: Intuitive:  Not a proof but intuition.  Suppose $f'(x) > 1$ everywhere.  At $f(n) = n$  then $f$ is increasing at a rate greater than $1$.  So $f(m) = f(n+h)$ must have increased by more than $h$.  So $f(m)=f(n+h) > f(n) + h= n+h =m$  Same thing if $f'(x) < 1$ everywhere. So it's not possible for $f'(x)$ to always be greater than or always less than 1.  So if it is never $1$ it must somehow "jump" from greater to less than 1 without passing through 1 in between.  But $f(x)$ is differentiable so the derivative is continuous.

Comment: @fleablood "*But $f(x)$ is differentiable so the derivative is continuous.*" Well, **no**?

Comment: @ClementC. differentiable on *all real numbers*.

Comment: @fleablood Differentiable and continuously differentiable are **not** the same thing.

Comment: @fleablood: What you said is true (derivatives have the Darboux property), but we don't necessarily know the derivative is continuous.

Comment: That's why I said "intuition"  not a proof.

Comment: @fleablood: That's poor intuition then, since the property I quoted is not as easy to prove as, say, the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Big Hint:**
Consider the function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(x)=f(x)-x$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, try to apply [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem). *(For reference: Rolle's theorem is the basic version of the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).)*

**Solution:** *(hidden, place your mouse above to reveal)*

> Consider the function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(x)=f(x)-x$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, $g$ is differentiable with $g'(x)=f'(x)-1$ for all $x$, and by our assumption on $f$ there exist two real numbers $x_1<x_2$ such that $g(x_1)=g(x_2)=0$. By [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), there exists $y\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that $g'(y)=0$. That is, equivalently, $f'(y)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists some $c$ between $n$ and $m$ such that 
$$\frac{f(n)-f(m)}{n-m}=f'(c)$$

Comment: I'm not too sure where to draw the line, but that's pretty far from a hint and pretty close to a solution, isn't it? :)

Comment: @ClementC. True, but I don't see how to make it closer to a hint....

Comment: The conundrum: once you say MVT, there is little more to be said...